# Geolocation always shows Moscow Javascript/JQuery/JSON (Open Weather API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geolocation

> **EDIT:** Just finished up the project. New link is up  here! http://codepen.io/myleschuahiock/full/pyoZge/

I'm in the process of making a Weather Widget App for my Free Code Camp. Everything except the "city" is a static placeholder. I'm using the Open Weather Api, which makes us to a latitude and longitude. For debugging purposes, I placed the longitude and latitude of my area underneath the time placeholder.

My problem is that when I statically input the lat and lon on my API link, it works just fine. It returns "Mandaluyong City", a nearby city where I live:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=14.603814400000001&lon=121.04907589999999&id=524901&APPID=ca8c2c7970a09dc296d9b3cfc4d06940
```

But when I do this, where I dynamically add mylatitude and mylongitude, to complete the API link:

```
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + mylatitude + "&lon=" + mylongitude + "&id=524901&appid=ca8c2c7970a09dc296d9b3cfc4d06940", function(json) {
$('.city').html(json.name);
```

I always get "Moscow" as my city.

Please take a closer look at my Javascript/JQuery code here!
http://codepen.io/myleschuahiock/pen/zqYzWm?editors=0010

Thank you very much! Much appreciated!

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous. So, you're calling `$.getJSON` before the location is actually determined. Easiest solution is to move the `getJSON` into the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback

Comment: @JaromandaX or move the `getJSON` into the if condition as you would only want to run the API if the clients allows the location. :P

Comment: @NewToJS - your suggestion confuses me ... the if condition is OUTSIDE of the callback I was referring to - why would I put the getJSON BEFORE or AFTER the callback, exactly the same problem would occur

Comment: @JaromandaX Look at my answer. Replace the javascript from the OP's codepen and replace it with the one I have posted.

Comment: @NewToJS - your answer does **exactly** what I suggested ... put the getJSON call inside the callback for `getCurrentPosition` - you continue to baffle me

Comment: @JaromandaX mybad I thought you were going down the same road as Nicholas O'Malley but placing another function call in the callback which would lead to creating another function for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution for you.

Move the `$.getJSON()` into your if condition, why attempt to query the weather if the client blocks the location?

> As **Jaromanda X** has pointed out:
>
> `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous. So, you're calling `$.getJSON` before the location is actually determined.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      $('.geo').html(position.coords.latitude+ " " +position.coords.longitude);
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&lon="+position.coords.longitude+"&id=524901&appid=ca8c2c7970a09dc296d9b3cfc4d06940", function(json) {
    $('.city').html(json.name);
  });        
  });
  }else{
    $(".geo").html("Please turn on Geolocator on Browser.")
  }
});
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: `why attempt to query the weather if the client blocks the location` - that's **not** why the original code failed

Comment: I never said that's the reason for the current source code not working... It's a question hence the question mark **?** It doesn't make sense to run the API if the client blocks the location. You have explained in the comments why it wouldn't work, unless you want me to copy/paste your comment into the answer...

Comment: I think the reason for moving the code is important in the answer - feel free to explain it in your own words :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Fair play! :p I have moved your comment into the answer but since you did offer the explanation I think it would only be fair you edit my answer with it... that way you also have some credit for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Added

```
  getName(mylatitude, mylongitude);
```

and changed

```
 $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + mylatitude + "&lon=" + mylongitude + "&id=524901&appid=ca8c2c7970a09dc296d9b3cfc4d06940", function(json) {
       $('.city').html(json.name);
    });
```

to

```
 function getName(mylatitude, mylongitude){
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + mylatitude + "&lon=" + mylongitude + "&id=524901&appid=ca8c2c7970a09dc296d9b3cfc4d06940", function(json) {
       $('.city').html(json.name);
    });
 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yqzvbd?editors=0010

Comment: your answer here is incomplete - you mention what you "Added" but not WHERE you added the call

Comment: Which is fine, as long as the codepen link exists, I guess

Answer (score 1):

You can use third-party IP API that provides the name of the city. With use jQuery function [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

```
var openWeatherMap = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
var APPID = 'APPID';
var ipAPI = 'http://ip-api.com/json/';
$.getJSON(ipAPI).done(function(location) {
    $('.geo').html(location.lat + " " + location.lon);
    $('.city').html(location.city);

    $.getJSON(openWeatherMap, {
        lat: location.lat,
        lon: location.lon,
        APPID: APPID
    }).done(function(weather) {
        $('#temperature').html(weather.main.temp - 273.15);
    })

})
```

OpenWeatherMap provides the temperature in Kelvin on this I did `weather.main.temp - 273.15` to get Celsius